# WiX default REFERENCED value OR Registry Value

Tags: wix

I need to set a default database file for my application.  I only want it to be set on initial installation.  If the registry value--a string of the path to the sdf file--changes, then future upgrades should not try to set the value back to the default.

Another caveat, that seems to be a problem, though, is that if they've never setup a database file, the user should be able to use the program with a default database without having to go through setup.

So I set the DATABASEFILE with value="[INSTALLFOLDER]dust.sdf".  but candle was complaining that [INSTALLFOLDER]:

```
The 'DATABASEFILE' Property contains '[INSTALLFOLDER]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes.
```

So, following the error's instructions, I added a custom action.  Now that custom action ALWAYS overwrites the DATABASEFILE attribute.  I want it to only override that value if the value doesn't exist in the registry.

Here's the code:

```
<CustomAction Id='SetINSTALLFOLDERREF' Property='DATABASEFILE' Value='[INSTALLFOLDER]dust.sdf' Execute='immediate' />

<Property Id='DATABASEFILE' >
  <RegistrySearch Id='DatabaseFile' Type='raw' Root='HKCU' Key='Software\DBG\Dust\Database' Name='File'/>
</Property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set conditions on your custom action with Id=SetINSTALLFOLDERREF? If not, you might want to do it.

A condition of NOT DATABASEFILE  on your custom action should probably suffice.

With the above condition,

-In the case of a fresh installation, the registry entry does not exist. Hence, DATABASEFILE is NULL, the custom action condition evaluates to true and the custom action SetINSTALLFOLDERREF executes.

-For any subsequent maintenance operations, the registry key is present, the property DATABASEFILE  will always contain a value, the custom action condition evaluates to FALSE and the custom action will not be triggered.

Another thing you might want to do is to add the property DATABASEFILE  to the list of SecureCustomProperties ie. secure the property DATABASEFILE.